# Lambda function does not extract event json data

Tags: node.js, angular, http, post, aws-lambda

In angular, i make a http request with headers and json data such as DynamicSend1.
In a lambda function, i try extracting that json data by doing event.DynamicSend1.
but this does not work, it cant extract that data in lambda and i have no clue why.
The DynamicSend1 data is successfully send to lambda in a body, i just dont know why i cant then extract it from lambda.

Heres my lambda code:

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(event.body),
  };
  
  return response;
};
```

heres my angular code:

```
let finalMessage = (message + " - " + signature).toString();

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    const body = { DynamicSend1: finalMessage };

    this.http.post(this.lambdaEndpoint, JSON.stringify(body), { headers }).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log('Lambda response:', response);
        this.success = true;
        this.resetAll();
      },
      (error) => {
        // Handle errors
        console.error('Error calling Lambda:', error);
        this.error = true;
        this.resetAll();
      }
    );
```

Thank you so much if you could help, you will save me literally.

I tried looking up so many things,
Anything i do i just cant extract it

Comment: What is the response you get when you call the lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Figured I had to add this

```
let dataDS1 = "";

if (event.body !== null && event.body !== undefined) {
  let body = JSON.parse(event.body) //use in case of JSON body
  dataDS1 = body.DynamicSend1;
}
```